# Do we need an [october] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

We don't have any "month" tags except for [october](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/october). I am struggling to work out when such a tag would ever be useful.

Should we delete it?

Comment: How many questions to the tag?

Comment: @Willeke Three (including one closed)

Comment: @MJeffryes it can safely be burned then.

Comment: I have deleted the tag from all three questions, should disappear now.

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion we do NOT need month tags. I have had a look at the three questions which have the `october` tag. In all cases the question is not about the month but about traveling in the time period in which October is central. Autumn/fall would have worked in two of the three, in my opinion.

Mostly it does not make much of a difference whether you travel in one month or in the next, just a few days difference.

Yes, people who describe a travel will often mention a month, but tags are to find questions and I have yet to meet the person who specialized in answering questions about one particular month.

Comment: And we already have an *oktoberfest* tag ;-)